# How do you get rid of the corners when using border radius

Tags: html, css

I've created a view and I'm trying to make it with rounded corners so I'm using `border-radius`.

The only problem is that I can see the corners of one of my `div` elements and I can't seem to get rid of them. I try to narrow down which element it was showing the borders with google developer tools but I can't pinpoint it.

Here is the [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ANBe7/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of parent having no border-radius, so you can add same `border-radius` to `.center_content`  class

```
.center_content {
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 border-radius: 15px;
}
```

or You can also remove the background from this class to achieve the same.

[JS Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/ANBe7/1/)

Comment: Alternatively, remove the `background-color` property

Comment: +1 @Kenneth yes, This is also a solution, I've added to my answer.